# Find all solutions to the equation $f(x+y)+f(x-y)=2x^2-2y^2$

Tags: functions

> Find all solutions to the equation $f(x+y)+f(x-y)=2x^2-2y^2$

What's the best strategy here?

I've tried substituting in values but I didn't get anything (if it was $2x^2+2y^2$ I could just substitute $y=0$ but the minus sign complicates the story).

The only other method  I know is isolation,but I don't think it's useful here.

Can you guys give me some hint ?

Edit:
The function in question looks similiar to some trig identity maybe ?

Comment: There are no solutions. y=0 gives $f(x)=x^2$ setting x=0 then gives a contradiction.

Comment: What is the contradiction when we set $x=0$ ?It forces $y$ to be $0$ ?

Comment: By solution do you mean all functions f that satisfies the equality for all x and y ? Or some pair x,y that satisfies the equality for some function f ?

Comment: It is meant for all pair $(x,y)$ I belive ,as the previous examples of my book do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would seem that there is, in fact, no solution. If we analyze two separate cases, we have:

- Setting $y = 0$ gives $f(x) = x^2$ for all $x$
- Setting $x = y$ gives $f(2x) = 0$ for all $x$

These two conditions are contradictory.

Comment: Alright thanks.So If I want to check if there aren't solutions I have to consider special cases and see if all of them are in contradictions to one another ?

Comment: @Mr.Y That's just the approach I always try: Look for special cases that simplify it down to a one- or zero-variable problem.

Comment: Got it.Thanks for the time .